# importing a class returns error and breaks my existing function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to import script.js into my app.js and it returns an error that says "Uncaught SyntaxError: import not found: script app.js:1:9" and also breaks getSelectedItems function and says that is also undefined. I included my HTML because I'm unsure if there could be an error there.

I'm trying to import this into app.js

```js
export class script {
  //Save movies into the local storage

  saveIntoStorage(item) {
    const items = this.checkStorage();

    items.push(item);

    // Add new array into the localStorage
    localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(items));
  }

  // return movies from storage
  checkStorage() {
    let items;
    // Check the localStorage
    if (localStorage.getItem("items") === null) {
      items = [];
    } else {
      items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("items"));
    }
    return items;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>My Website</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <h1>Welcome to My Website</h1>
  </main>
  <script src="app.js" type="module"></script>
  <script src="script.js" type="module"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is from my app.js

```js
import {
  script
} from "./script.js";

// Store the user input from dropdown menu into a new array
function getSelectedItems() {
  const items = document.getElementsByClassName("selectVal");

  myApp.results = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    const item = items[i];
    const userInput = item.options[item.selectedIndex].value;
    myApp.results.push(userInput);
  }
}
```

Comment: You have not exported script from your script.js file

Comment: @AbinThaha when I export the script.js getSelectedItems is still undefined

Comment: Because the export works only with Es6. Can I know what you are trying to achieve here ? You need to create some reusable function and use it in another file ?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. The scripts load without errors when I test that code.

Comment: @AbinThaha yeah so I created a class inside script.js and I'm trying to access the two functions inside of script.js within app.js

Comment: @Quentin weird, I'm still getting an error. Do you think it could be a live server issue or something?

Comment: I also tried to reproduce and had no problems... how are you accessing / serving the page ? e.g. are you using something like webpack ?

Comment: @steff_bdh I'm accessing the page through vscode with live server enabled. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Using type of module for the script tag fixed the error for me.

```js
<script src="./app.js" type="module"></script>
```